# Display BitLy Shortened URL in Base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, bit.ly

I would like to display the (result) of the below code in base64.

The below code shortens inputted url and display its bitly result but i want it to encode the result in base64 instead.

i.e it would have shortened the inputted url to bitly in hidden but will display only the base64 encoded result.

For example, if a particular shortened url result is

> http://bit.ly/url

it should display

> aHR0cDovL2JpdC5seS91cmw=

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //bit_url function
  function bit_url(url) {
    var url=url;
    var username="username"; // bit.ly Api username
    var key="BitLy Key"; //bit.ly Api key
    $.ajax({
      url:"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
      data:{longUrl:url,apiKey:key,login:username},
      dataType:"jsonp",
      success:function(v) {
        var bit_url=v.data.url;
        $("#result").html('<a href="'+bit_url+'" target="_blank">'+bit_url+'</a>');
      }
    });
  }


  $("#short").click(function() {
    var url=$("#url").val();
    var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    var urltest=urlRegex.test(url);
    if(urltest) {
      bit_url(url);
    } else {
    alert("Bad URL");
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
Enter URL:
<input type="text" placeholder="http://"" name="url" id="url"/>
<input type="submit" id="short" value="Submit"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `btoa()` to encode the bit.ly urls.  Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //bit_url function
  function bit_url(url) {
    var url=url;
    var username="username"; // bit.ly Api username
    var key="BitLy Key"; //bit.ly Api key
    $.ajax({
      url:"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
      data:{longUrl:url,apiKey:key,login:username},
      dataType:"jsonp",
      success:function(v) {
        var bit_url=v.data.url;
        var encodedUrl = btoa(bit_url);
        console.log(encodedUrl);
        $("#result").html('<a href="'+bit_url+'" target="_blank">'+bit_url+'</a>');
      }
    });
  }


  $("#short").click(function() {
    var url=$("#url").val();
    var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    var urltest=urlRegex.test(url);
    if(urltest) {
      bit_url(url);
    } else {
    alert("Bad URL");
    }
  });

});
```

More information on encoding and decoding base64 in JavaScript is available in the developer docs here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. However this keep giving dW5kZWZpbmVk as result in console log. Meaning "undefined" when decoded. Can you please try this on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Julius the code needs *your* bit.ly username and API key to work. As it is right now it probably wont return anything meaningful until that's changed.  I wont be able to put it into a fiddle, beacuse I don't have your API information.

Comment: I purposely removed it before posting. i did input it when testing and it sure shortened the url but didn't encode. The encode result was what i posted above. Was hoping you'll have a bitly API key and username to test it out.

Comment: I overlooked the ajax request, you'll probably be able to fix it by moving the encode function so it executes with the ajax success.  I updated the answer as an example.